# Equivalence relation: Proof

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

Given a measurable space $(X, \mathbb A)$. For any $x \in X$, let $x* = \cap A$ for $x \in A \in \mathbb A$.

If on $X$ the following binary relation is defined: $x\sim y$ where $x, y \in X$ if for any $A \in \mathbb A$ it holds $x \in A$ if and only if $y \in A$.

I want to prove that $\sim $ is an equivalence relation on $X$. To do so, I have to show that the relation is symmetric, reflexive and transitive. But how, only as example, do I check if $\sim $ is really symmetric (by not saying that it's obvious `;)`)?

Comment: Please clarify what the part of the first line with $x*$ is about. Is it in any way related to the relation defined afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you reformulate your definition of the relation it gets clearer:
$$x\sim y :\Leftrightarrow \{A\in\mathbb A: x\in A\}=\{A\in\mathbb A: y\in A\}$$
then basically all the desired properties follow from the fact that $=$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Ok, all right. But how to show that $x*$ is the equivalence class of $x$ with respect to ~ ? [This is a slightly different question than my initial one ;) ]

Comment: Therefore you first need to clarify your definition of $x*$ do you mean $x*:=\cap\left\{A\in\mathbb A:x\in A\right\}$? If this is the case $x*$ is a set and the relation makes no sense for $x*$

Comment: We defined $x* = \cap A$, but the question which is asked says that one should show that $x*$ is the equivalence class of x with respect to ~.

Comment: how do you define the symbol $\cap A$?